# Why Electron doesn't use cached video file?

Tags: javascript, video, electron

In my Electron app,I use the html video element below to play mp4 video looply:

```js
      <video
        ref={this.onVideoRef}
        autoPlay={true}
        loop={true}
        src={this.videoSrc}
        preload="auto"
      ></video>
```

and the src points to a CDN(https) url, the video size is more than 190MB. I found it always fetch the video from cdn with whole size, the the status code is always 206(Partial Content) instead of 304(Not Modified). The server response header has cache-control: max-age=86400, and also has etag and last-modified fields. It didn't use the cached video file locally.(sometimes it didn't fetch whole video from server, I don't know why)
[image]

And when I request the video file in Chrome directly, it will response 304, don't fetch whole video from server
[image]

I tried to add the code be low in my Electron app to set the cache size to 250MB, but it doesn't work

`app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disk-cache-size', '256000000')`

Is it true that Electron doesn't support caching video files when using the video element in an HTML file? or any other problem when use video in Electron? How to let it use local cached video file? My electron version is v19